# UCM Idoc scripting Cannot find the parameter 'wfAction'. error

Tags: webcenter, oracle-ucm

im trying to detect the workflow action outcome so i can make a custom logic and this is the code

```
<$if wfAction like "APPROVE"$>
    <$wfSet("wfJumpName", "returntoOriginal")$>
    <$wfSet("wfJumpTargetStep", "reveew@newWorkFlow")$>
    <$wfSet("wfJumpReturnStep", wfCurrentStep(0))$>
    <$wfSet("wfJumpEntryNotifyOff", "0")$>
    <$wfReleaseDocument()$>
<$endif$>
```

this code is generated , i didn't write any line but when i try to test the script i get the following error :

```
Cannot find the parameter 'wfAction'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you testing that code in the context of a workflow approval/rejection? That is the only time that `wfAction` would be present. You can see what is in the context by adding this code before the `if` statement.

`<$trace("#all", "#console")$>`

This will dump all local variables, result sets, and environment variables to the system console. More information on the `trace()` function can be found [in the Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/webcenter/content/12.2.1.4/webcenter-content-develop/idoc-script-functions-and-variables.html#GUID-F4F5DB78-0A01-457E-8AEE-031606C0BE11).